# Install ZeroBrane Studio on Linux

Tags: linux, zerobrane

I downloaded `ZeroBraneStudioEduPack-1.40-linux.sh` and ran it, but I cannot find the IDE anywhere.

Here is the output when I ran `./ZeroBraneStudioEduPack-1.40-linux.sh`

```
# ./ZeroBraneStudioEduPack-1.40-linux.sh
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing ZeroBraneStudio with EduPack 1.40.......
Installing ZeroBrane Studio 1.40...
./install.sh: line 18: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 19: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 21: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 25: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 25: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 25: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 25: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 25: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 25: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 25: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 30: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 39: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 40: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 42: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 44: sudo: command not found
./install.sh: line 45: sudo: command not found
Done.

To uninstall ZeroBrane Studio at a later time, run:
    zbstudio-uninstall
```

Here is my linux information:

```
Linux fatdog64-e6c 3.18.7 #1 SMP Mon Nov 16 01:58:11 WIB 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It seems like `sudo` is broken/missing in your installation. Maybe try running `apt-get install --reinstall sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

You can open this `.sh` in `vim`, kill lines with `d` till binary data, after rename `.sh` to `.tar` and open.

Inside you'll see a folder `app` - this is your studio.

File `zbstudio.sh` should looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$(uname -m)" == "x86_64" ]]; then ARCH="x64"; else ARCH="x86"; fi
(bin/linux/$ARCH/lua src/main.lua zbstudio "$@") &
```

i.e. we just removed `cd "/opt/zbstudio";` from it.

Comment: There is a more straightforward option as you can pass --keep option to the installation archive, which will unpack all the files and keep them. I updated the installation instructions to cover this case: https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-installation#linux

Answer (score 0):

This is a shell script. It needs to be run at the command line.
On Ubuntu open a terminal and navigate to the directory containing the file and type:

```
/bin/bash ZeroBraneStudioEduPack-1.40-linux.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the other answers got to the point... Here's what you need to do once you downloaded the script:

`sudo ./ZeroBraneStudioEduPack-1.90-linux.sh`

And to start it, (this is not well documented, surprisingly):

`zbstudio`